# jQuery function .submit() not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

Can't really figure out why this code isn't working.

I create a list of links from a MySQL query, and classify them to open a jQuery dialog onClick. Here's how I generate links and all the script stuff:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#select" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 280,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        },
        buttons: [{
            text: "Close",
            click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }]
    });

    $( ".perm" ).click(function() {
        $("#select").dialog("open");
        $("#cod").val(this.id);
        $("#pass").submit();
    });
});

//And then generating links

echo "<a id=\"".$fetch['id']."\" href=\"#\" class=\"perm\">Click me</a>\n";
```

And there's the div containing an iFrame, which will be opened into the dialog, and SHOULD be able to read that hidden value submitted by the jQuery function through the form into the div.

```
<div id="select" title="Blabla">
    <form id="pass" target="iframe" method="post" action="permcom.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="idcom" id="cod" value="">
    </form>
    <iframe id="permcom" name="iframe" src="permcom.php"></iframe>
</div>
```

I also tried to use `event.preventDefault();` but nothing happens. Dialog opens, displays the iFrame correctly but no data can be found in the POST array.

My only purpose is to send the id of the element that fired the function to the iFrame through POST, in order to make other operations without closing or refreshing the page.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Try `$( ".perm" ).on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: Also try `echo'<a id="'.$fetch['id'].'" href="#" class="perm">Click me</a>\'\n';`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use jQuery normally to access an iframe's contents. Also, I have no idea what your form is doing. It's completely wrong. You can send POST data with AJAX, send WITHIN an iframe, or outside it, but not send the form INTO the iframe. That doesn't make any sense.

Assuming the form is INSIDE the iframe, you need to do something like:

```
$("#permcom").contents().find("#the-form").submit();
```

So you can access elements inside the iframe, just NOT with a normal form submit. You'll need to mess around.

Comment: I've found that my problem is jQuery animations. I used an animation on dialog open/close, and noticed that it refreshes the page just after the animation ends.

Solved putting the POST data into SESSION array, directly from the frame page:

`if(isset($_POST['idcom'])) $_SESSION['idcom']=$_POST['idcom'];`

Thanks anyway :)